# http post redirect to generated url

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, http-post

I wonder if anyone can help. I have a form that when submitted uses http post to submit data and request a url. I get the url displayed in a browser but I want the user to be automatically redirected to the generated url.

```
<form id="form_52393" class="appnitro" action="https://test.dekopay.com:3343/" method="post">
<div class="form_description">
<h2>Finance Application Form</h2>
Enter the course name, its price, the term of you finance and your deposit. You will then be redirected to an online application form to complete the process. Below is my form code.

</div>
<ul>
    <li><label class="description" for="action">action</label>
<div><input id="element_9" class="element text medium" maxlength="255" name="action" type="hidden" value="credit_application_link" /></div></li>
    <li id="li_5"><label class="description" for="Identification[api_key]">Identification[api_key] </label>
<div><input id="element_5" class="element text medium" maxlength="255" name="Identification[api_key]" type="hidden" value="be803c55eeaf79c89b6ff46ac6a9a039" /></div></li>
    <li id="li_6"><label class="description" for="Identification[InstallationID]">Identification[InstallationID] </label>
<div><input id="element_6" class="element text medium" maxlength="255" name="Identification[InstallationID]" type="hidden" value="13161" /></div></li>
    <li><label class="description" for="Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]">Identification[RetailerUniqueRef] </label>
<div><input id="element_7" class="element text medium" maxlength="255" name="Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]" type="hidden" value="test999" /></div></li>
    <li id="li_1"><label class="description" for="Goods[Description]">Course Name </label>
<div><input id="element_1" class="element text medium" maxlength="255" name="Goods[Description]" type="text" value="" /></div></li>
    <li id="li_10"><label class="description" for="Goods[Price]">Price </label>
<span class="symbol">£</span>

<input id="element_12_1" class="element text currency" name="Goods[Price]" size="10" type="text" value="" /> .
<label for="element_12_1">Pounds</label></li>
    <li id="li_4"><label class="description" for="Finance[Code]">Finance Type </label>
<div><select id="element_4" class="element select medium" name="Finance[Code]">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="ONIF6">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 6 month term</option>
<option value="ONIF9">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 9 month term</option>
<option value="ONIF10">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 10 month term</option>
<option value="ONIF12">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 12 month term</option>
<option value="ONIF18">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 18 month term</option>
<option value="ONIF24">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 24 month term</option>
<option value="ONIF36">Interest Free Credit (0% APR) 36 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB12-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 12 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB18-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 18 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB24-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 24 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB36-12.9">Low Rate Credit (12.9% APR) 36 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB12-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 12 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB18-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 18 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB24-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 24 month term</option>
<option value="ONIB36-24.9">Classic Credit (24.9(% APR) 36 month term</option>
</select></div></li>
    <li id="li_12"><label class="description" for="Finance[Deposit]">Price </label>
<span class="symbol">£</span>

<input id="element_12_1" class="element text currency" name="Finance[Deposit]" size="10" type="text" value="" /> .
<label for="element_12_1">Pounds</label></li>
    <li class="buttons"><input name="form_id" type="hidden" value="52393" /><input id="saveForm" class="button_text" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Below is the php that the form submits to that should retrieve the url and redirect the user but currently the script runs and the url is displayed with no redirection.

```
<?php
    $interface = "https://test.dekopay.com:3343/";
    $postFields = Array(
        "action" => "credit_application_link",
        "Identification[api_key]" => "be803c55eeaf79c89b6ff46ac6a9a039",
        "Identification[InstallationID]" => "13161",
        "Identification[RetailerUniqueRef]" => uniqid(),
        "Goods[Description]" => "",
        "Goods[Price]" => "",
        "Finance[Code]" => "",
        "Finance[Deposit]" => "",
    );

    function httpPost($interface, $postFields)
    {
        $curlSession = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $interface);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        return $curl_response = curl_exec($curlSession);
    }
    header('Location: ' . httpPost($interface, $postFields),True);
    exit();
```

For reference I have also included a screenshot of the current outcome. Sorry for the length but I have been stuck on this for about a week and wanted to be as clear as possible.

Current outcome of running the script
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: did you try putting httpPost(interface, $postFileds) in 1 variable but instead of using , you use .
`$test = $interface.$postFields;` . and then 

`header('Location: '.$test);`

Comment: What is the output of `httpPost()`? Are you sure it returns a valid URI?

Comment: It definitely returns a valid url, if i copy and paste it into a browser I get taken to a website to complete an appplication

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jurick, I've tried that but still got the same outcome.

Comment: if your echo prints the right URL, then i have no idea why the header wont work. Just curious tho, what do you see in your address bar when u put `header('Location: ' . httpPost($interface, $postFields),True);`

Comment: It shows "https://test.dekopay.com:3343/" see the image I added to the original post.